# How does the C++17 proposal for uniform call syntax intend to handle namespaces?

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++17

As far as I know, there are two propsals for uniform call syntax for C++17 (where the other one is called unified call syntax).

Reading them, I cant see how they intend to handle namespaces.

Example:

```
class Class {...}
namespace MyNamespace {
  void f(Class x, Class y);
}
```

Will it be possible to call this method using something like:

```
Class a, b;
a.MyNamespace::f(b);
```

Or do both the free function, and the class need to be defined in the same namespace?

*References*:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4174.pdf

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4165.pdf

Comment: As a personal note, i'd find it really neat if something like this, which enables chaining of function calls, where added to the C++ standard. Utilizing the pipe operator, as boost range and Eric Nieblers range v3 is just complicated (plus is has the disadvantage of having lover priority than operator==)

Comment: Current EWG direction is to allow `f(x, y)` to call `x.f(y)` if ordinary lookup fails to find a viable `f`, and not the reverse. I don't think there's a paper nailing down all the details yet, but I'd be surprised if they want to touch qualified calls.

Comment: Seems it didnt make it, and yes I'd be surprised to, but verry happy!

Answer (score 3):

Update: C++17 does *not* get unified call syntax at this time. Motion does not pass. #cpp #cpp17

https://twitter.com/ericniebler/status/705855444049399808