# Where is the proposal for standardization of "extension methods" in C++?

Tags: c++

I forgot the exact term used to describe the feature that was used in the proposal I saw about a year (maybe more) ago. it looked similar to C# extension methods in that a global function defined as part of a class's interface could be invoked using class-member syntax. Very very dumbed down example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void One();
};

void Two(Foo&);

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.One();
    f.Two(); // This was valid in the proposal I saw
}
```

I'm sure my code example is way off, but I'm using it more to try to communicate the feature I remember seeing. Am I completely off here or was there a proposal out there for C++ that introduced this mechanism? And if so, could someone point me to the proposal and possibly its status/timeline?

Comment: Unified Call Syntax proposal: https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/02/a-bit-of-background-for-the-unified-call-proposal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a proposal for Unified (var Uniform) Call Syntax for C++. From 10,000 feet PoV, it will allow extensions methods a la C# as well as really blending the difference between method call and function call for a given object.

Here is short description how this feature would look like

https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/02/a-bit-of-background-for-the-unified-call-proposal

As far as I know, it didn't make it into C++17 (too late?), awaiting for c++2x

Comment: Looks like it was voted down for C++17: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376985/how-does-the-c17-proposal-for-uniform-call-syntax-intend-to-handle-namespaces

Comment: It is kind of a shame as after doing some C# programming recently I have definitely seen how it easy to string together a lot of functions with this.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I would agree - nice to have and saves some time. From the other hand, it is not a "big deal" proposal, and a lot of small details to be ironed out. Say, ranges or modules sound and look a lot more sexier to play with and would mean a lot more for general C++ development. Still, keep finger crossed...

Comment: Yeah.  I'd rather have modules, ranges or concepts first

Answer (score 5):

Roger Orr and I proposed adding extension methods to C++ (17) in 2015 in this paper:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0079r0.pdf

The (Language) Evolution group were not convinced that this was a direction they were keen to pursue.

I think that extension methods in C# are a nice feature but this does not seem to be a truth universally acknowledged.

I do not intend to re-raise the proposal for C++20.

#### Brief summary

(as requested by einpoklum)

Uniform call syntax proposed that member functions could be called with free function syntax:

```
void foo(const A& a);
class B { void foo(); };

A a;
foo(a); // calls foo(const A&);

B b;
foo(b); // calls b.foo();
```

Extension methods proposed that suitably written free functions could be called with member function syntax:

```
void foo(const A& this); // note the name `this` is important
class B { void foo(); };

A a;
a.foo(); // calls foo(const A&);

B b;
b.foo(); // calls b.foo();
```

Comment: `I do not intend to re-raise the proposal for C++20` why not?

Comment: No one has expressed any interest in pursuing the proposal any further. Given that the universal call syntax proposals that were under discussion at the time of our original proposal have not been advanced, perhaps appetite for extension methods has changed?

Comment: Could you add a couple of sentences explaining how this differs from having uniform call syntax?