# Class doesn't have the member function

Tags: c++, friend-function

I was trying normal friend function. And I got stuck at this point. It is showing that class Complexnos has no member add.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complexnos
{
    private:
    int real,img;
    public:
    void read()
    {
        cout<<"Enter the Real and Imaginary numbers : ";
        cin>>real>>img;    
    }

    friend Complexnos add(Complexnos c1, Complexnos c2);
    
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"The addition of the Complex numbers is : "<<real<<" + "<<img<<"i";
    }

};

Complexnos add(Complexnos c1, Complexnos c2)
{
    Complexnos c;
    c.real = c1.real + c2.real;
    c.img = c2.img + c2.img;
    return c;
}
int main()
{
    Complexnos c1;
    Complexnos c2;
    Complexnos c3;
    c1.read();
    c2.read();
    c3 = c1.add(c1,c2); <-- Having error here! 
    c3.display();
    return 0;
}
```

This code is adding 2 complex number using friend function

Comment: `friend` functions are free functions, not members.

Comment: Does `Complexnos add(Complexnos c1, Complexnos c2);` from the class match `Complexnos add(Complexnos c2)` from the global space?

Comment: `c.real = real + c2.real;` What is this freestanding `real`? Where does it come from?

Comment: No [Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax) in C++ ([not passed in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39063668/2684539))

Comment: Sry guys, My bad, I pasted the wrong code.

Answer (score 1):

Your line below declares a **free function** that takes **two parameters**.

```
friend Complexnos add(Complexnos c1, Complexnos c2);
```

But your usage here assumes a non-free **member function, taking one parameter**.

```
c3 = c1.add(c2); <-- Having error here!
```

If you are genuinely attempting a friend function use:

```
add( c1, c2 );
```

Comment: I believe this answer still gets to the problem, even after the question was changed.

Comment: I have changed the answer to match the current version of the question.

Comment: Still Same Problem

Comment: @PrathamYadav there is no problem [when I try it](https://godbolt.org/z/aTb9G6).  It compiles.