# Is it possible to make a C++ function for a data type that is accessible using a dot operator?

Tags: c++

I want to make a function associated to a data type say int that can be accessed using the dot operator such that:

```
int x = 9;
std::string s = x.ToString();
```

I know how to do so with std::string and the likes but not the int data type. Is that possible?

Comment: FWIW, [this is something being asked for](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4474.pdf), but I can't find any information on where it stands or how likely it is to be accepted.

Comment: Actually, found it did not pass a vote for C++17: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376985/how-does-the-c17-proposal-for-uniform-call-syntax-intend-to-handle-namespaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. An `int` is a primitive type whereas a `std::string` is a class type that contains methods.

However, you could create your own struct/class in order to implement this functionality. The `struct Int` type has a constructor which takes in an integer and uses an initializer list `:a(value)` to assign the internal integer with a given value.

```
#include <string>

struct Int
{
    int a;

    Int(int value)
        : a(value)
    {}

    std::string ToString() const { return std::to_string(a); }
};

int main()
{
    Int a = 20;
    std::string s = a.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Constructor initialiser lists were not introduced in C++11.   They have been in all C++ standards since 1998.   C++11 introduced uniform initialisation and the `std::initializer_list` templated type, but they are something different.